# Data not getting in AngularFire with Ionic and Angular Application

Tags: angular, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-realtime-database, angularfire

I'm getting error and also data is not getting in Angular and ionic application using angularfire for firebase.

package.json :

```
"dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/core": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/forms": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/http": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "5.0.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "5.0.3",
    "@ionic-native/core": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/splash-screen": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic-native/status-bar": "4.4.0",
    "@ionic/pro": "1.0.16",
    "@ionic/storage": "2.1.3",
    "angularfire2": "^5.0.0-rc.1",
    "firebase": "^4.4.0",
    "ionic-angular": "3.9.2",
    "ionicons": "3.0.0",
    "rxjs": "5.5.2",
    "sw-toolbox": "3.6.0",
    "zone.js": "0.8.18"
  },
```

service for firebase :

```
constructor(public afDB: AngularFireDatabase) {
    console.log('Hello FireBaseServicesProvider Provider');
  }

  getStockUserList(){
    // let getData = this.afDB.list().
    return this.afDB.list('stock/').valueChanges();
    // this.afDB.list('stock/');
  }
```

in page.ts file :

```
    stockList: Observable<any>;
this.stockList = this.fbService.getStockUserList();
```

in html :

```
<ul>
    <li *ngFor="let item of stockList | async">
      {{ item.age }}
    </li>
  </ul>
```

in firebase stock list is having name and age with the unique key .
add is working but data getting from firebase having issue and also displaying "ngFor is only for array elements " and

```
typescript error
            Cannot find type definition file for 'firebase'.
```

Comment: have you setup correctly as given https://github.com/angular/angularfire2/blob/master/docs/ionic/cli.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go back to firebase 4.8.0:

- In your CLI with you project path type: `npm uninstall firebase` 
  then once fish uninstall, type: `npm cache clea`r
- Then type: `npm install firebase@^4.8.0`
- finally: Remove `"firebase": "^5.0.0-rc.1"` in dependencies in `package.json` and Type `"firebase": "4.8.0"`